# test haproxy, varnish and apache configuration

Tags: redhat, haproxy, varnish

I'm installing Varnish cache 4 behind a HAproxy which is behind an Apache instance. 
I've got several questions that could seem trivial to you (sorry then):

1. How can i know if the HaProxy calls Varnish ? (Answered)
2. How can I find the HAProxy adress to call ?

Edit : The configuration is : `Àpache`->`HAProxy`->`Varnish`->`HAproxy`->`CMS`
Thank in advance.

PS : I'm also a novice in server configuration

Comment: Your setup looks like `apache` -> `HAProxy` -> `varnish`? Regarding your first question: Check the `HAProxy` logs. Regarding the second: What do you mean by "right port"? What is the "right port"? Settings like this are defined in the config.

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. 
I edited the second question. I've got actually a Varnish listenning to an HAProxy Which is loadbalancing to two apaches. How can i find which IP (of HAProxy i presume) to put in the backend of the Varnish ?

Comment: So your setup is like `varnish` -> `HAProxy` -> `apache`? Are all these services on the same machine?

Comment: Actually, there are several machines (one for each, except for apache where there are two each time)
There is the configuration `Àpache`->`HAProxy`->`Varnish`->`HAproxy`->`CMS`

Comment: Oh well...your setup seems "a bit" complicated to me, not sure why you're doing this. Anyway: You want to find out the ip of the second `HAProxy`, right? It depends on your config, which you didn't provide, but, by default, it listens for all addresses on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you've configured things but in general if you don't get to see anything when you point your web browser to your site, then things are horribly broken.

If pages do get displayed, odds are that things are working more or less as intended :)

Normally I would expect an HTTP request to traverse the following logical path (with redundancy left out):

```
----------        -------------         ---------         --------
 Internet |  =>  | HA-proxy LB |  ==>  | Varnish |  ==>  | Apache |
----------        -------------         ---------         --------
```

Where requests for cached content on Varnish won't need to be forwarded to Apache.

> How can I know if the HaProxy calls Varnish?

By monitoring the logs, if you configured them and alternatively by running [`vanishtop`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/statistics.html#varnishtop) with the appropriate flags on the varnish server.

> How to know if Varnish listens to the right port?

If you see activity for maybe? (see your previous question) `[sudo] netstat -plnut` is another method.

> How can I test if the default.vcl is called ?

How do you [start Vanish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/starting_varnish.html)? The initial config is loaded with the `-f` switch.

Once Varnish is running use the command line interface [`vanish-cli`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnish-cli.html) :

> > **`vcl.list`**
> >     List all loaded configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson ! It helped me understand better the problem !

Comment: @IsmaH I was composing my ASCII art before you edited your question to include your config, but the reason I wouldn't implement an HA-proxy loadbalancer between varnish and Apache is because varnish is perfectly capable of balancing requests (that don't come from its cache) over multiple back-end servers by itself

Comment: Actually, i don't have the chance to change the architecture.  It is something that has been mandated. I've read that Varnish is capable of round robin and stuff like that, but is it capable of load balancing like an HAProxy ?

Comment: It depends a bit on how complex your needs are: but there are more options than just round-robin although the manual  still calls it [basic load balancing techniques](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_directors.generated.html) out of the box and more [advanced options](http://info.varnish-software.com/blog/proper-sticky-session-load-balancing-varnish) as well and the whole idea is of course that one uses varnish so that the back-end servers don't hammered in the first place :)